# Load event not being triggered in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions, browser-extension

I'm working on a browser extension, and I need specific code to run when the new window is loaded. The below code works perfectly in Chrome/Edge:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
  handle_data();
});
```

This event is never triggered in the Firefox version. Alternatively, I tried:

```js
window.onload = handle_data;
```

But this is called *before* the DOM of the page is loaded. Any idea why this is an issue in Firefox?

EDIT: The script is executed using the following:

```js
function open_tab() {
  chrome.tabs.create({
    url: "https://www.test.ca/apd/myad",
    active: false
  }, function (tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, { file: "manage_content_script.js" });
  });
}
```

And is called on the click of the extension, using the following code in background.js:

```js
if (msg.content == "clicked") {
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "dom_script.js" });
      open_tab();
    }
```

Comment: The two code snippets run code at exactly the same time so the issue is caused by something else. Show us how this script is loaded/defined/declared and where (content script, extension popup, etc.)

Comment: @wOxxOm updated to include mroe details

Comment: Try adding `, runAt: 'document_start'` after the file name. If it won't work, the problem may be that Firefox doesn't load resources in inactive tabs i.e. in backgrounded tabs. Note that by default executeScript runs script after DOMContentLoaded so maybe you don't need to wait for `load` event. Instead you can use MutationObserver to detect when a certain DOM element appears.

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `window:pageshow` event.

For more information, you can check official documentation at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/pageshow_event)

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried `DOMContentLoaded`?

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    console.log('DOM fully loaded and parsed');
});
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event

Comment: Unfortunately I get the same result - the event is never triggered.

Comment: i tried 'DOMContentLoaded'  also this is not working